# Notepad ++ Append filename when using Save All

Tags: notepad++, notepad, save-as

I'm hoping for some help in appending the files names in multiple open files when saving them all.

For example I have file1, file2 and file3 open.  I want to save them all at once and rename them file1a, file2a and file3a when doing so.

Any easy way to do this?  Doing it one by one right now.

Prefer without adding plugins if possible as this is at my office who are not open to users adding plugins and the like on their own.

Thanks for any advice!
Tom

Comment: Write a macro...